# Webmock not registering my request stubs correctly

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking, request, stubbing

I am registering a request stub as follows:

```
url = "http://www.example.com/1"
stub_request(:get, url).
  with(body: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<project>\n    <id>1</id>\n</project>\n",
       headers: {
         'Accept' => 'application/xml',
         'Content-type' => 'application/xml',
         'User-Agent' => 'Ruby',
         'X-Trackertoken' => '12345'
       }).
  to_return(status: 200, body: '', headers: {})
```

for some reason when I run `bundle exec rspec spec`, my specs fails saying that the request isn't registered yet. The registered stub is this,

```
stub_request(:get, "http://www.example.com/1").
  with(body: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<project>\n    <id>1</id>\n</project>\n",
       headers: {
         'Accept' => 'application/xml',
         'Content-type' => 'application/xml',
         'User-Agent' => 'Ruby',
         'X-Trackertoken' => '12345'
       })
```

*note that the `to_return` part is missing*

I tried replacing the `body` header with an empty string, the request stub is registered correctly but then my specs will still fail because they are expecting some value from the body other than the empty string. Thus, it is really important that I assign a value to body.

In my spec I am calling this method:

```
def find(id)
  require 'net/http'
  http = Net::HTTP.new('www.example.com')
  headers = {
    "X-TrackerToken" => "12345",
    "Accept"         => "application/xml",
    "Content-type"   => "application/xml",
    "User-Agent"     => "Ruby"
  }
  parse(http.request(Net::HTTP::Get.new("/#{id}", headers)).body)
end
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the relevant spec code?

Comment: @shioyama, in my spec I am calling this method:

    `def find(id)
        require 'net/http'
        http = Net::HTTP.new('www.example.com')
        headers = {
          "X-TrackerToken" => "12345",
          "Accept"         => "application/xml",
          "Content-type"   => "application/xml",
          "User-Agent"     => "Ruby"
        }
        parse(http.request(Net::HTTP::Get.new("/#{id}", headers)).body)
      end`

Comment: I don't understand why you're including a `body` inside the `with` of the stub if you're not passing a body in your actual request. The solution seems to me to be just take out the `body` in the `with` of the stub, and put that value into the `body` part of `to_return`. Or am I mixed up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your stub is matching a GET request with a non-empty body of `<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<project>\n    <id>1</id>\n</project>\n`, but when you make the request you're not including any body, so it doesn't find the stub.

I think you're confused about what body is what here. The body in the `with` method arguments is the body of the *request* you are making, not the body of the *response*. What you probably want is a stub like this:

```
url = "http://www.example.com/1"
stub_request(:get, url).
  with(headers: {
         'Accept' => 'application/xml',
         'Content-type' => 'application/xml',
         'User-Agent' => 'Ruby',
         'X-Trackertoken' => '12345'
       }).
  to_return(status: 200,
            body: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<project>\n    <id>1</id>\n</project>\n",
            headers: {})
```